# currentNode object gives NullPointerException

Tags: aem, sling

In my component's JSP, if I want to reference the current node using `currentNode` object, it throws a `NullPointerException` and the whole component then throws a `ScriptEvaluationException`

My component JSP does have the `global.jsp` included at the top. I guess currentNode object is created by the global.jsp

Strangely, the component throws these exceptions only in a particular site. It works fine in others.

What possible could be the reason for this ? In what conditions does the `currentNode` object be NULL ?

Comment: What is the context? What kind of node are you trying to get from where?

Comment: I have a custom search component added to my page template. There, I need to get the Query object using "currentNode.getSession().getWorkspace().getQueryManager().createQuery()" but the currentNode is null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe your component is a [synthetic resource](http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/resource/SyntheticResource.html)? If you have include tag like this:

```
<cq:include path="mynode" resourceType="myapp/components/somecomponent" />
```

and `mynode` doesn't exist, the included component *will* be renderer, however you can't referer to the node properties in `somecomponent` code.

In this case `resource` variable will be a `SyntheticResource` and `currentNode` will be `null`.

**Update:**

If you don't really need the `currentNode` but `QueryManager` object (as your comment says), you can use `resourceResolver` object to get it:

```
resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class).getWorkspace().getQueryManager()
```

Comment: I have used the <cq:include> . But I didn't understand - "and mynode doesn't exist". AFAIK, when we add a component using <cq:include>, the "path" variable (mynode) will be created anyway.. Is it not the case ?

Comment: `<cq:include>` doesn't create any new nodes. Check it yourself ;)

Comment: I've updated my answer with a hint on getting `QueryManager` object without using `curretNode` object.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that the node is created only after the include of the component after drag and drop. So if that is not the case, you will not be having your node inside `/content/your-site/`